# EMF Sensors - Tri-axial Inductors vs Tri-axial Magnetometers

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, magnetic-flux

I took apart a bunch of EMF sensors (such as [this one](https://www.alphalabinc.com/product/uhs2/)) and found that almost all of them instead of having a magnetometer inside, have usually three inductors. In the case I just shared, it has 3 33mH inductors, each orthogonal to each other. Here's a picture

[image: Inside an EMF sensor]

My question: There are tons of off-the-shelf magnetometer ICs that you can buy now, such as the [MLX90393SLW](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Melexis/MLX90393SLW-ABA-011-RE?qs=KuGPmAKtFKWTlMmUHhqzlg%3D%3D) or [LIS3MDLTR](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/LIS3MDLTR?qs=hnsWAVXnr6EbLE48dGN9Pg%3D%3D). Why do engineers of these types of sensors use the three inductor configuration instead of a magnetometer IC? Both approaches seem to have similar maximum values and resolutions. What's the deal?

Comment: I doubt this instrument is capable of using these two-wire inductive "sensors" to measure static magnetic fields. For **alternating fields**, yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are probably picking up AC magnetic fields in the ~10hz to 200kHz range (look at the datasheet to see if they define it). Typically magnetometers pick up magnetic signals lower than 100 Hz to DC for direction finding.

Comment: the linked store page says 13Hz-75kHz

Comment: Thought it would be in that range...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question (I think) is that when building a handheld EMF sensor you don't want to have to worry about zeroing out the Earth's static magnetic field. In theory, the magnetometer is the same thing but you'll have to do additional work to zero out the Earth's field from the readings. Inductors don't have that problem unless you're moving.